# MYSQL using order and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have the following statement

```
SELECT * FROM cds  
WHERE genre='rock'  
GROUP BY cat_no  
ORDER BY ABS(track) DESC  
LIMIT 0,3
```

Each CD has a row in the db for each track and another entry for the cd as a whole which instead of a track number is called 'bundle' (but only if the CD has more than one track) the above statement will select three of the 'bundle' entries but I want to be able to select the latest 3. If I use ABS(date,track) it doesn't work.

Table

```
genre cat_no  track  date
rock  001     1      09323123
rock  001     2      09323123
rock  001     bundle 09323123
rock  002     1      09323123
rock  002     2      09323123
rock  002     bundle 09323123
rock  003     1      09323123
rock  003     2      09323123
rock  003     bundle 09323123
```

Comment: What you expect from query with SELECT * FROM and GROUP BY ???

Comment: you need to be more precise on what the table looks like and what exactly it is you want as a result.

Comment: I want the latest three bundles by date or if there is no bundle then track 1.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT * FROM cds  
WHERE genre = 'rock'
ORDER BY ABS(track) ASC
LIMIT 0, 3;
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM cds  
WHERE genre = 'rock' AND track = 'bundle'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 3;
```

Comment: Sorry I should of said I need to order by track because sometimes there isn't a bundle entry just a single track for that 'release'

Comment: @user1209203: So what about the first query...does it do what you need? If not, perhaps update your question to include your expected result.

Comment: @user1209203: Or perhaps take a look at the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function.

Comment: You first answer is the same as what I wrote in the question, it groups by genre and orders by track but I need to then order these results by date.

Comment: There is no `GROUP BY` in my first query. To order these results by date, change the `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY ABS(track) ASC, date DESC`. `GROUP BY` is used for [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), like `MAX` and `SUM`.

Comment: Sorry you're right but this will give a result for every entry, I need to use group by to get one result per 'release'